# Android RFComm VR App

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, android

I have been toiling over an application that I am hoping will be able to send information from an Android phone to my Raspberry Pi 3, via Bluetooth. I have put together code from various similar projects. I have a main activity in which I simply have a Title and a start button. The press of the button starts the 2nd activity, which is a simple side by side webView, which will be used to view 2 web pages that house separate video streams (this app will be used for a VR Headset). Within that 2nd activity, I would like to read the phone's accelerometer measurements and send it over serial to the Pi, where I have a Python client script to handle the input (for now just simply reading and printing).

Here's my class to handle the Bluetooth connection:

```
package com.example.jbooda21.sdvideostream;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
* Created by jbooda21 on 7/7/16.
*/
public class BluetoothSerial {

private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
private OutputStream outputStream;

private static final String DEVICE_MAC = "A0:B4:A5:07:1C:89";
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

public void connectOK() {
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(DEVICE_MAC);
    try {
        bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        bluetoothSocket.connect();
        outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    try {
        if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
        if (bluetoothSocket != null) bluetoothSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bluetoothDevice = null;
    bluetoothAdapter = null;
}

public void send(byte[] data) {
    try {
        outputStream.write(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private BluetoothDevice getDeviceByName(BluetoothAdapter adapter, String name) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : adapter.getBondedDevices()) {
        String thisDevice = device.getName();
        if (name.matches(thisDevice)) {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

I have my MainActivity.java file that is, again, very basic:

```
package com.example.jbooda21.sdvideostream;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button startVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);

    startVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent vid_request = new Intent (MainActivity.this, VideoStream.class);
            startActivity(vid_request);
        }

    });
  }
}
```

And I just stuck all of the sensor information handling, as well as the video streaming in one .java file:

```
package com.example.jbooda21.sdvideostream;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class VideoStream extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
protected static BluetoothSerial bluetoothSerial;

private boolean enabled;
private double xPos;
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];

private WebView leftVideo;
private WebView rightVideo;
private String l_url;
private String r_url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_stream);
    startOK();

    leftVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.leftEye);
    rightVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.rightEye);

    l_url = "https://www.raspberrypi.org";
    r_url = "https://www.raspberrypi.org";

    setUpEye(leftVideo, l_url);
    setUpEye(rightVideo, r_url);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    leftVideo.destroy();
    rightVideo.destroy();
    stop();
}

private void setUpEye(WebView webView, String url)
{
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

/**
 * Set up the wake lock to keep the screen on for as long as the service is running
 */
private void setUpWakeLock() {
    PowerManager mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "Test");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}

private void startOK() {
    setUpWakeLock();
    setUpSensors();
    try {
        bluetoothSerial.connectOK();
        enabled = true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        enabled = false;
    }
}

private void setUpSensors() {
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    Sensor accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

private void stop() {
    if (mSensorManager != null)
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    if (mWakeLock != null)
        mWakeLock.release();

    if (bluetoothSerial != null)
        bluetoothSerial.disconnect();

    enabled = false;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            xPos = event.values[0];
            ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(xPos);
            bluetoothSerial.send(bytes);
            break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
            break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    Log.d("Test", "Sensor : " + sensor.getName());
    Log.d("Test", "Accuracy: " + accuracy);
}
}
```

Where I'm coming up short is, on my Pi, I run:

```
$ sudo rfcomm listen XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 1
```

Which is the same command I run to listen for connection between the Bluetooth Terminal App from the play store, and it works just fine.

I've released the channel and re-run the listen before re-running my app on the phone I've been testing on. Still the Pi cannot get a connection from my application.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Could anyone assist at all as I'm running out of self generated solutions.

Please and thank you all.